# Error Importing matplotlib.pyplot due to PySide

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyside, qtgui

I am getting this error when attempting to run code and import matplotlib.pyplot

I've checked and all of matplotlib's dependencies are installed as well as all the dependencies for PySide. I'm not too knowledgeable about the nuts and bolts of the program and software itself, so if anyone has other suggestions of what I should be looking for to be installed, I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtGui.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN7QLayout11adoptLayoutEPS_
Referenced from: /Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtGui.so
Expected in: /Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui
in /Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtGui.so
```